# Authenticate to SQL Server 2016 using service account (or) AD Account

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to Login from Java (Open JDK 11 , Jdbc, Springboot) with the below JDBC Driver

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.0.jre11</version>
</dependency>
```

For security reason, our org will not create a SQL Server username/password, but a AD service account like

**SOURCING/svcAdmin** (SOURCING is domain, svcAdmin is AD Account to login)

There are many forums, telling to use jtds - I am not so keen on using that, is it possible to use native ms-sql jdbc driver and connect, can you please help?

Comment: Have you read this document?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#connecting-using-activedirectoryintegrated-authentication-mode What part of it is not working for you? Error message?

Comment: do you have found a solution with the official mssql driver?

Comment: String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://server.cloud.azure.com:1433;databaseName=xyz;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;userName= svcAdmin@ SOURCING.domain.com;password=<password>";

Add the krb5.conf file to project and if required add this to run time

-Djava.security.krb5.conf=<PATH_TO>/krb5.conf

Comment: @denfri.dev This worked, but lately we are moving away from MS-SQL to AzureSQL Serverless for cost saving and it supports many modes